# Discord Bot Python 3.6 Error importing commands

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import commands,has_permissions, MissingPermissions
import json

with open('reports.json', encoding='utf-8') as f:
  try:
    report = json.load(f)
  except ValueError:
    report = {}
    report['users'] = []

client = discord.ext.commands.Bot(command_prefix = '?')
```

When I run this this comes. if I give from `discord.ext import commands,has_permissions, MissingPermissions` Then this come `ImportError: cannot import name 'has_permissions'`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Rubayet\Discord Bots\Discord.py\Test.Bot\Test.Bot.py", line 2, in <module>
    from discord.ext.commands import commands,has_permissions, MissingPermissions
ImportError: cannot import name 'commands'
```

I dont know know why. Plz help me out with this.

Comment: You have to break your import statements to correctly import the modules. You cannot import commands from commands. Try ```from discord.ext import commands``` and then ```from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions```

Comment: i did it and it worked but `MissingPermissions` was missing so i did 
from discord.ext.commands import MissingPermissions but it raise a exception
ImportError: cannot import name 'Missing_Permissions'

Comment: Can you update which discord package you are using because i dont see any module named ```MissingPermissions``` inside discord.

Comment: i'm really sorry.....Forgot those things. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

[`MissingPermissions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.MissingPermissions) is available only in the rewrite branch.  If you don't have that, you need to uninstall `discord.py` then run

```
pip install -U git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py@rewrite#egg=discord.py[voice]
```

Then you can reorganize your imports.  Either import `commands` and reference everything through that import, or import everything you use individually.  Don't do both.

```
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(...)
...
```

or

```
from discord.ext.commands import Bot, has_permissions

bot = Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.command()
@has_permissions()
...
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming you're using [Rapptz/Discord.py](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py) You cannot import commands from commands folder. No such thing.

I believe you you're looking for the [core](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/async/discord/ext/commands/core.py) class's `has_permissions` method:

```
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions
```

You will need to define your own error for `MissingPermissions`

```
class MissingPermissions(Exception):

#and here's a "custom" check example
def has_perms(**perms):
    if has_permissions(perms):
        return True
    else:
        raise MissingPermissions
```

Comment: This will still fail for the commands module import. You are not managing that in your answer. Check my comment for that.

Comment: Oops, sorry was away from computer to check with my code. And didn't see you're comment.  haha thanks! *edited*

Comment: Define your own method and check to see if they have that permission